# Change to two columns

Tags: two-column, document-classes, lncs

I have a paper written in [LNCS](http://www.springer.com/computer/lncs?SGWID=0-164-6-793341-0) style. Is there any easy way to convert it to a two-column style? Simply using /two-column doesn't work as the columns are narrow, lines overflow, and it looks terrible overall. I tried switching class files, but then everything started to break (in particular, my definitions, author lists etc.)

Is there any style sheet or class that will turn this class into nice looking two-columns that is compatible with the environments used in the original?

Comment: The document class `llncs` is a front-end with specific settings for the `article` document class. By executing `\twocolumn` (or specifying `twocolumn` as a document class option), you get -- well -- *two narrow columns*. You must re-arrange any wide document elements, such as equations and tables, to fit the altered layout of the document. You're not exactly giving a lot of information what these elements look like right now, so it's not possible to provide specific advice as to how you might achieve this objective.

Answer (score 1):

You can use style files that are specially designed for papers in conferences or journals. Samples that you can use:

http://www.icassp2014.org/PaperKit.html#Templates
http://www.ieee.org/publications_standards/publications/authors/author_templates.html

Comment: But you will still have to reformat your equations using split and align to get them to fit.

Comment: Basically if one is interested in writing a two-column document, he needs to do the necessary re-formatting; however, there are options that one can use to put the equation in one-column mode in a two-column document!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `multicol` package.

```
\begin{multicols}{#_of_columns}
Text or content in multiple columns.
\end{multicols}
```

You can find further information [here](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Multiple_columns).